# Pair of normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

> $S=(S_1,S_2)$ is called **normal** iff $S_1S_2=S_2S_1$ and both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are normal.

Assume that $F$ is an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

> I look for an example of two normal operators $S_1$ and $S_2$ (which are not a scalar multiple of the identity) such that $S_1S_2=S_2S_1$ and $S_1\neq S_2$.

Comment: How about $S_1 = I$ and $S_2 = 2I$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right but I hope to get a non trivial example and thank you for your help

Comment: My point is that you should be clear about what "non-trivial" means in this context

Comment: Notably, every finite dimensional example can be thought of (up to a change of basis) as a pair of diagonal matrices.  Would versions of these examples be considered "trivial"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Please see my edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a family of examples that you might find interesting.  Take any two bounded sequences $(a_n),(b_n)$.  Define the maps $S_i:\ell_2 \to \ell_2$ by
$$
(T_1x)_n = a_nx_n, \qquad 
(T_2x)_n = b_n x_n
$$